# Reversible process and reversible cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

Is there a difference between the two when it comes to how entropy behaves?
I am thoroughly confused regarding reversible process for a system, irreversible process, rev cycle, irreversible cycle, entropy behavior for isolated/closed/opened system. And if things such as irrev./rev. process of an isolated/closed/opened system  exist and how entropy behaves. Also how does entropy in all the above case behaves when you also take into consideration the environment. As you can see there is a multitude of combinations between type of processes, types of systems for the entropy. Is there a detailed pdf/link etc that gives a clean explanation regarding all the above cases and combinations.

Example: We say that the entropy change of an rev. process is zero. But if we observe an isothermal rev. gas expansion, clearly the gas entropy changes with $\log \frac {V_2} {V_1}$ which implies a non zero change and it looks like the above statement is wrong, when in fact if you take also into consideration the entropy change of the environment, which is negative then the sum of the two changes gives us zero. Follow up question: We say that the entropy is zero or positive, but for the enviroment in the rev. isothermal gas expansion that is not the case. Is there some mis-explanation or am I making a mistake by saying that the entropy of the environment becomes smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already said that the entropy change of the combination of system and the surroundings (environment) is zero in a reversible process.  This is correct.  But, for an irreversible process, the entropy change of the combination of system and environment is positive.  So, irrespective of the process, the entropy change of the combination is positive or zero.

From this it follows for the system alone, the entropy change has to satisfy the Clausius inequality:  $$\Delta S\geq \int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}$$where dQ is the heat transferred from the surroundings to the system and $T_B$ is the temperature at which the heat transfer takes place (i.e., the temperature at the boundary interface between the system and surroundings).  The equal sign applies if the process path experienced by the system is reversible, and the > applies if the process path is irreversible.

Comment: One question. Leaving reversibility aside for a moment  When a system goes from a state A to a state B, in statistical mechanical terms, we know that the entropy is the log of the multiplicity of the macrostate in which the system is in. Assuming that in state B the multiplicity is bigger then in state A, then we have an increase in entropy. Now if the change is rev. the system changes entropy but the total entropy of the surrounding +system doesn't change. If we go from B to A (cycle) is it wrong to say that the entropy of the system decreases? At the same time I assume the entropy of the

Comment: surroundings increases, to keep the tottal entropy to zero. Which means $\Delta S_{total -A \longrightarrow B}=0$ and $\Delta S_{total - B \longrightarrow A}=0$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: But if you observe only the entropy of the system from A to B and then reverse. Assuming again that B has higher multiplicity than A, which implies an entropy increase. In thermodynamic terms  the entropy of the system increases from A to B and it decreases from B to A, even tho we jumped to each state via a rev. process. So entropy can be smaller then zero, but it doesn't contradict the 2nd law simply because I am not considering the environment, which would keep the entropy (for the rev. case) to zero. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you have said is correct.

Comment: thx for the confirmation

Comment: @imbAF Have your doubts been resolved?

Comment: @BobD to a certain extend they have Bob. Usually I get confused when I need to jump to a thermodynamic interpretation from a statistical mechanical one. But for the moment I am more knowledgeable in the topic. Though I will have questions in the future

Comment: @imbAF OK. It sounds like Chet has resolved your doubts from a thermodynamics viewpoint.

Comment: @BobD It sounds like there is more that you would like to add?  Please feel free to chime in.

Comment: @ChetMiller Not really. I just felt that your answer should be accepted if it resolved his non statistical mechanics issues.